# Unique Constraint Violated on Hibernate Select Query

Tags: hibernate, select, unique-constraint

```
return ((LimitSum) getSession()
.createQuery("SELECT ls FROM LimitSum ls  WHERE ls.limitClass.id = :limitClassId AND ls.customer.id = :customerId")
.setLong("limitClassId", limitClassId)
.setLong("customerId", customerId).uniqueResult());
```

This is my hiernate query, but it shows the following error:

> ORA-00001: unique constraint (MOBR5.IDX_UQ_LIMIT_CL_ENTITY) violated

I don't know how is it possible if a constraint is violated in select query.

Please help.

Comment: try  =>  createQuery("FROM LimitSum ls  WHERE limitClass.id = :limitClassId AND customer.id = :customerId")
.setLong("limitClassId", limitClassId)
.setLong("customerId", customerId).uniqueResult());

Comment: If not working suggest to upload more details like structure of LimitSum Model and complete stack trace.

Comment: post complete stacktrace